# Running automated tests on several C files

Tags: c, bash, algorithm, automated-tests, software-design

I have several files in the structure

```
/algorithms
    /a1
        a1.c
    /a2
        a2.c
    /a3
        a3.c
```

Each of these files contains a function of the same name. Each has the same signature, except for the name (which is the same as the filename). Essentially, each algorithm is a different implementation of the same thing -- different means to the same end. There may however be small helper functions.

The content of the files (comments, functions, layout, etc) cannot change.
I want to create some method that will test each algorithm. This method *is not* confined to being implemented in C.

I have a C file that essentially contains three functions:

```c
// Runs the algorithm, which modifies the given integer array.
void run(void (*algorithm) (int*, size_t));

// Checks that the algorithm successfully completed and
// the array is correct.
int check(int*, size_t);

// Should call run() with appropriate algorithm and a random data set
// and then call check() to make sure it worked.
int main(int, char**);
```

I need an automated way of including the appropriate files and then calling
the function within them. Currently, I have a bash file that gets all the algorithms, copies the tester file, prepends an `#include` statement at the beginning and a generated `injected_main()` function that gets called by the actual `main()` function. It runs the copied tester and then deletes it.

```sh
function testC() {

    local tempout=temptest.c
    local filename="$(basename -- $1)"
    local functionname="${filename%.*}"
    local main="void injectedMain() {test(&$functionname);}"
    local include="#include\"$1\"\n$main"

    touch $tempout
    chmod +x $tempout
    printf "$filename: "
    cp $TESTER_C $tempout
    printf "$include" >> $tempout
    gcc $tempout -o tempout -Wall -Wextra -pedantic
    ./tempout
    rm $tempout tempout

}
```

Where the function is run in a loop for every algorithm C file.
However, this method is prone to error, not extendable, and just downright ugly. Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: What ways are trying to improve this? You say it is run in a loop, what are the arguments to the function you are feeding? the whole path `algorithms/a1/a1.c` and so on? Are you satisfied with the approach and just want to improve it? and what is `TESTER_C`

Comment: ```TESTER_C``` is the path to C test file (literally named ```tester.c```). And yes, the path passed to the function is absolute file path to each algorithm file. I'm not satisfied with the approach in that it's very obtuse and difficult to change. Aside from changing the directories to look in, it's very much write-only code.

Comment: You could compile each .C into a shared object then load with dlopen

Comment: @AnttiHaapala Can you expand on that?

Comment: No, on my phone and soon in flight mode :))

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Combine your existing code and @Herve's answer.

You could let the bash script just collect all algorithms and build a C source like that proposed by @Herve. This way there will be no error prone manual step.

To run all tests compile this automatically generated source and link it to your test runner. Let the latter loop through `all`.

Answer (score 1):

Can't you just a header including your algorithm implementations and loop through all of them?

Something like

```
#include "a1/a1.h"
#include "a2/a2.h"
#include "a3/a3.h"

typedef void (*AlgorithmImplemetation)(void); //Your algorithm function signature goes here

AlgorithmImplemetation *all = {
    a1,
    a2,
    a3
};
```

Then include this header in your `main.c` and loop through `all`.

Comment: There are potentially hundreds of algorithms. Adding them one by one manually would be a lot of work. If one was removed, I'd have to account for that too.